# Is the executeBatch() performed on Oracle is done in order?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

This is more of a kind of theory question to understand how the executeBatch() request is handled by Oracle.

Consider there are three insert statements (PreparedStatement) ,say statement 1, statement2 and statement 3 are added to execute as a batch using executeBatch() method  and over Oracle. Will there be a chance that the execution of statement 2 to complete even before statement 1 completes? In other words, can the insert operation by statement 2 succeed before the insert performed by operation ?

Provided Autocommit is set to false.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Provided auto-commit set to false

Then the answer is straight-forward if you are concerning on querying in the middle of insert (as you have mentioned in comment on another answer):

Given that in same connection, you cannot do query before your previous insert statement finished, that means your query needs to be from another connection.

In Oracle, before any insert/update/delete is committed, the change is not visible to other connection.  That means, the query will see the snapshot before any insert is done, until you commit the change.

Then you should have no concern about the insert order in such aspect.

Comment: Thanks, so if otherwise if the auto commit is set to true, will the insert order matter?

Answer (score 4):

The database will execute your statements in the order you put them into the batch.

There is no out-of-order or concurrent execution.

Comment: Thanks, If I happen to query the table (where records are been inserted) at the time when the insertion is happening, is there a chance that I get the record inserted by statement 2 but not the record inserted by statement 1, but the same query after a moment returns both the records? Basically I trying to build a test case on the above question.

Comment: A proof (a way to verify the order of execution) to support the above answer see this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1326781?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: @Vishnu seems the discussion you quoted has nothing to do with the problem.  It is incapable to determine the insertion order (i.e. the order of execution).

Comment: The above link suggests that the insertion order can be different from what is provided and cannot be controlled, looks contradicting to Thilo's answer.

Comment: Not really. The order of statements is the same order as they have in the batch (the linked thread asserts that with a reference to the API documentation). But the physical layout of rows in a table cannot be controlled, and the retrieval order of rows in a SELECT without ORDER BY is also unspecified.

Comment: "query the table at the time the insertion is happening". That can only happen from another connection. That connection will not see any uncommitted changes. The changes you make in your transaction will become visible atomically (all or nothing) when you commit.

Comment: @AdrianShum please read the post fully where a user has specified if you need to make sure the insertion order is guaranteed by making use of auto generated sequences.

Comment: @Vishnu I have, and what I got is not what you got.  What I got is: "if you need ordering of *records*, you need to explicitly maintain it (by extra column etc), instead of relying on insertion order/row ID for which is out of your control.  "  Which also implies that, you shouldn't care about the *insertion order* for any ordering, because that is supposed to be out of picture of user.  There is no way you can verify the actual insertion order base on that discussion (although using a sequence is close enough)

Comment: @AdrianShum, the insertion order that i am talking about is the order in which you add to the batch (using java api add) not at the db level. As this question is order of execution of statements in batch.

Comment: @Vishnu so what you are talking about is even more unrelated to OP.  He is concerning about the order that the records are actually inserted to DB (hence affecting the result he is querying at the same time of insert).

Answer (score 0):

> When a batch is processed, operations are performed in the order in which they were batched.

[Oracle Database JDBC Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraperf.htm#JJDBC28753)